# SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy simple example issues

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-web-api, eventaggregator

I'm trying to use SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
library, but I cannot get my head arround the docs or the demos. I do not need to use Ninject and I'm only after very simple tes app with WEB API on server side and Angular SPA.

Here is what I Have so far:

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();

        var proxy = new Lazy<IEventAggregator>(() => new Eventer());
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IEventAggregator), () => proxy.Value);

        app.MapEventProxy<Message>();
    }
}
```

message classes

```
public abstract class Message {}

public class MyMessage : Message
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Eventer.cs class firing events

```
public class Eventer : IEventAggregator
{
    public void Subscribe(Action<object> handler)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            int number = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                handler.Invoke(new MyMessage { Number = number++ });
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

simple app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module("TestApp", ['signalR.eventAggregator']);

    app.controller("TestCtrl", ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {

        function onEvent(e) {
            console.log("event received => ", e);
        };

        $scope.eventAggregator().subscribe(EventAgrTest.Events.MyMessage, onEvent);

        $scope.headerText = "HEADER";
    }]);
})();
```

and index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="TestApp">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR.eventAggregator-1.4.141.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="/eventAggregation/events"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="TestCtrl">

    <h1>{{headerText}}</h1>

    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR.eventAggregator.angular-1.4.143.0.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the app I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" error pointing to line

```
signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(type, function(e) { ...
```

in jquery.signalR.eventAggregator.angular-1.4.143.0.js

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what.

There is part in the Wiki called Implement constraint handlers (https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki/Implement-constraint-handlers) per which it should be as simple as inheriting from abstract class, but I'm not sure what needs to inherit from this class.

[image: console output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the order of JS dependencies in index.html file.

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

should be before

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR.eventAggregator-1.4.141.0.js"></script>
```

Here is how it should look like ...

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR.eventAggregator-1.4.141.0.js"></script>
<script src="/eventAggregation/events"></script>

<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR.eventAggregator.angular-1.4.143.0.js"></script>
```

it does make a sense ... now ...

Comment: Ah, true missed that. Will make that more clear in the docs. I might change in the future so that the client script (jquery.signalR.eventAggregator-1.4.141.0.js) does not directly inilize a event aggregator. Then the order is not has crucial. That will be a breaking change because then the user of the library needs to inilize the event aggregator instead

Comment: I ensured that this wont happen again https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/commit/f438fe7994b1151d296bd6534cde1657f81cc2a8

Answer (score 1):

im the author of the library,

It was not designed to use simple data types as messages.

You need a message base class for example

```
public abstract class Message {}
```

Create a actual message

```
public class MyMessage : Message 
{
    public int Number { get;set; }
}
```

Now in the config change use the base class, this is a way to let the library know which messagss should be proxied to javascript

```
app.MapEventProxy<Message>();
```

In your event proxy change to

```
handler.Invoke(new MyMessage { Number = number++ });
```

Now in your client change to

```
$scope.eventAggregator().subscribe(EventAgrTest.Events.MyMessage, onEvent);
```

I should update the Invoke method from taking type object to take a generic type with constraint class

Comment: thank you! this have explained a bit more, but the error is still there. I have updated the question to include you sugestions. in addition there is another error "Uncaught TypeError: CAnnot read property 'client of undefined" refereing to jquery.signalR.eventAggregator-1.4.141.0.js line 152.

Comment: Is EventAgrTest.Events.MyMessage really proxied correct? if you do console.log(EventAgrTest.Events.MyMessage) is it a object? Any other errors in the console?

Comment: I hope it is. the Code above reflects exactly the one I'm running. I've added console screenshot with console log for EventAgrTest.Events.MyMessage...

Comment: It fails on this row, https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.eventAggregator.js#L152 Seems SignalR client library is not included correctly

Comment: thats where the error is thrown, but on line 151  $.connection.eventAggregatorProxyHub returns undefined ... so this.hub is undefined and the code on line 152 fails

Comment: Yes, seems there is something wrong with your SignalR setup. (The hub is not recognized by SignalR).